# highlight text box border color for few seconds?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i want to highlight a text box border color for few seconds , afterwards i want to change it back to  white color. is ther a way for addClass function to specify time also. Any other way ?tried with http://jsfiddle.net/RW2s4/7/ not working

Comment: See comments below for why your jsfiddle doesnt work.

Answer (score 12):

This little script added the class 'highlight' for two seconds to the input field:

```
$('#text').change(function() {
    var jElement = $(this);
    jElement.addClass('highlight');
    setTimeout(
        function() { jElement.removeClass('highlight'); },
        2000
    );
});
```

Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/tyPct/).

Or [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RW2s4/15/) the combination of your and mine solution.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RW2s4/15/) the combination of your and mine solution (without jquery ui).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `switchClass`, something like:

```
$("#element").switchClass("removeThisClass", "addThisClass", 1000)
```

Demo Fiddle: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/tK3Sv/1/)

Reference:[JQuery Docs](http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/)

Comment: Try here http://jsfiddle.net/RW2s4/11/ you didn't put the tick in the JQuery UI box on the left (underneath the jQuery dropdown). You need that. Also, click events in the markup don't work in jsfiddle for some reason. I've moved it into the JavaScript. Try that

Comment: @mattytommo - FYI onclick in the markup does work in jsfiddle, but not if your javascrip is `onDomLoad` or `onLoad` as they're enclosed outside of the window scope. Just choose `head (no wrap)` if you want normal events (which you almost never do using jQuery). So fixing that jsfiddle is as easy as ticking jQuery UI and changing the dropdown: http://jsfiddle.net/RW2s4/14/

Comment: @Jamiec ah didn't know that thanks :). I'll stick with `click` events in jquery vs `onclick` in markup though, better practice wouldn't you agree? :)

Comment: @mattytommo - totally 100% agree. But helps debug others jsfiddles to know.

Comment: @Jamiec yeah definitely, it did always bug me that I couldn't get that work, especially when debugger other's code. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Highlight div on click slide to div

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    var jElement = $(this);
    jElement.addClass('highlight');
    setTimeout(
        function() { jElement.removeClass('highlight'); }, 
        500
    );
    //$(window).scrollTop($('.box3').offset().top,100);
    $("html, body").delay(100).animate({
        scrollTop: $('.box2').offset().top 
    }, 2000);

});


    <button>http://jsfiddle.net/tyPct/198/    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

See live   [Demo](http://jsbin.com/izeluj/4)

```
$(function(){

  setTimeout(ChangeBorder, 2000);

  function ChangeBorder() {
     $(".highlight").css({"border-color":"red"});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check jquery animate function which animates the element after some interval:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/umSkg/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ogColor = $("#inpt").css("border-left-color");
    $("#trggr").click(function(){
        var inpt = $("#inpt");
        var delay = 1000;
        inpt.animate({ borderColor: "#EAC117" }, delay,function(){
        //revert after completing
        inpt.animate({ borderColor: ogColor }, delay);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Did you try your demo? It fails to revert back for me in FF12 (Works in IE8 though!)

Comment: Bizarre workaround, border-left-color works in FF but not border-color. You're right though... now works!

Answer (score -3):

Use the effect function

`$('#component').effect("highlight", {color: 'red'}, 2000);`

Comment: `effect` is not a built-in jquery function

Comment: @TinkerTenorSoftwareGuy who said it was? OP doesn't specify to be.

Comment: Providing such a solution is equivalent to my saying thusly, write $('selector').solveMyProblem(args) and calling it a solution. It offers no practical help.

Comment: the solution could be as simple as that, now if you want to build a whole plugin just for that go ahead.